# Are Sylow p-subgroups in conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group and $p$ be a prime number.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a chain of p-subgroups of $G$ ordered by inclusion. Then, for every element of the union of $\mathscr{C}$ has an order $p^n$ hence it's a p-subgroup. Applying Zorn's lemma, $Syl_p(G)$ is nonempty.

This proof gives no information how Sylow p-subgroups are associated and I'm curious whether they are in some relation.

Let $H,K$ be Sylow p-subgroups of $G$.

Then, does there exist $g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}=K$? (Just like finite case?)

Comment: Why would all the $p$-subgroups be finite?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I never said that every $p$-subgroups are finite.. Where did I say that?

Comment: Ohh, I misread, sorry.

Comment: In general it is false, though some other parts of Sylow theorems are true in general. Read the first 1-2 pages here for a general view about this issue in a  57 years old paper about this by the great B. H. Neumann:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is no. For example, let $G$ be the direct product of countably infinitely many copies of the symmetric group $S_3$. Then $G$ is countable, but it has uncountably many Sylow $2$-subgroups, so they cannot all be conjugate.

Comment: What exactly is meant here by infinite direct product? Finitely supported sequences of elements of $S_3$? I was under the impression that the infinite direct products denotes _all_ countable sequences of elements of $S_3$ with componentwise operations, which is definitely uncountable.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant finitely supported sequences. A long time ago, I was taught that "direct product" implied finite support, whereas "cartesian product" was used for unrestricted support. I have long since realized that not everybody uses this convention. Perhaps "restricted direct product" would be clearer?